# ESLint/VSCode marking valid imports as unresolved

Tags: visual-studio-code, eslint

[image]

Having problems with the ESLint plugin for VSCode. It's marking a lot of inputs that are valid as unresolvable. Dunno how to fix it :/ Local server still runs fine despite the linter marking problems but it's really annoying seeing errors everywhere that aren't errors. My coworker thinks it has something to do with BABEL_ENV variable?

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had specified the paths property on the tsconfig.json file but I was still facing the error on vscode but whenever I was running eslint via CLI the issue wasn't reported.

If you read the description of the eslint plugin on vscode there's asection that talks about `eslint.workingDirectories` which fixed it for me when I set that option to `{"mode": "auto"}` on the vscode settings

Answer (score 0):

I guess your import statement like `import Foo from "@/components/Foo"`.

If you import like this, you should setup compiler settings in `tsconfig.json` or `jsconfig.json`, like below

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    "paths": {
      "@/*": ["src/*"]
    }
    ...
  },
  ...
}
```